# How to use lower_bound() on set of pairs?

Tags: c++

I have given a `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` and an integer `x`, I have to find the iterator to the first pair whose first element is greater than or equal to the given integer `x`.

I learned that if `s` is a `set<pair<int, int>>` and `{x, y}` is the pair then I can use `s.lower_bound({x, y})`. But, in my case I have to care only about the first element `x`. So, my question is how to use `lower_bound` on `set<pair<int, int>>` when I only care about the first element?

Comment: Tak a look at overloads of `std::lower_bound`. There is an option to provide custom comparator.

Comment: @Zereges That won't help. The `set` is sorted with respect to the default comparison function that ships with `std::pair`. `std::lower_bound` assumes a sorted sequence, but when you pass in a different comparison function, this won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The core issue is that your `std::set` instance is already sorted, but with the default [`std::pair` `operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp). You cannot intuitively use the member function `std::set::lower_bound`, as this uses the comparison function of its class type. You can't use `std::lower_bound` with a custom predicate neither, as this assumes a sorted range - but sorted with respect to the given predicate, which is not the case.

But there is a workaround for this specific scenario. Note that for each value of `x` in the set, the minimal associated value of `y` is the minimal value of type `int`. As the comparison operator for `std::pair` instances does a member-wise comparison, you can combine this to:

```
#include <set>
#include <limits>

const std::set<std::pair<int,int>> s{
   {42, 0}, {42, 1}, {43, 0}, {43, 1}
};

const auto entry = s.lower_bound({43, std::numeric_limits<int>::min()});
```

This will always find the *first* or *minimal* desired entry in the subset that correspond to the given value for the `std::pair::first` data member. Only the first value is of significance, as the second one is immediately *not less than* `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, which is what `lower_bound` is searching for.

If you need this functionality many times, it might be worth putting it into its own helper function (template), e.g.

```
template <class T>
auto lower_bound_first(const std::set<std::pair<T, T>>& s, T first)
{
   static constexpr T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();

   return s.lower_bound({first, min});
}
```

which you can invoke as

```
const auto entry = lower_bound_first(s, 43);
```

for any underlying value types for which the `std::numeric_limits` specialization is available.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way without constructing a temporary `pair`. All one needs is to define `operator<` between the pair and the other type. To avoid messing up with global definition of `operator<` for `pair` and `int`, define it for a wrapper:

```
template <class T>
struct Wrapper
{
    T value;
};

template <class T>
bool operator<(const std::pair<T, T> & x, Wrapper<T> value) {
    return x.first < value.value;
}
template <class T>

bool operator<(Wrapper<T> value, const std::pair<T, T> & x) {
    return value.value < x.first;
}

int main() 
{
    // NOTE: using std::less<>, instead of the default std::less<std::pair<int, int>>
    std::set<std::pair<int, int>, std::less<>> s {{1,2}, {1,3}, {4,1}, {5,1}, {5,2}};
    Wrapper<int> x{2};
    auto it = s.lower_bound(x);
```

This is an overkill for `std::pair<int, int>`, but for more complicated types like `std::pair<int, MyFancyClass>` it can be costly to construct the smallest possible object. Also, for infinite-precision numbers, no such value exists. In that case, one must resort to the above technique. For more complicated types, it may be possible to simply overload `operator<`, without using a wrapper.

Note that the overloaded operators must be consistent with each other. They must be subject to the same order of elements.